# Error with Azure Function and Docker

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-functions

I am trying to implement the ICS creator sample for Azure Functions: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-functions-create-ics-file-using-csharp-sample.

I followed all the steps there, but the difference with my implementation is that I'm running the function locally with Docker, and I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> CompilationErrorException: Script compilation failed.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker+d__26.MoveNext()
>   in DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs, line 313
>
> FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.swinvite
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

Per my understanding, the error is related with the ical.net library, that is not being imported to the image. 
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, error is related to `Ical.net` library. You can try [this repository](https://github.com/JohnReeson/Azure-Functions-CSharp-Locally-Create-ICS.git).

**More details**

The guide you follow is to create function in function runtime 1.x(.net framework), where packages will be restored according to `project.json`. But you want to run using docker(image uses runtime 2.x, based on .net core), where `project.json` is invalid. So the file can be dropped.

Then we have to add `Ical.Net` related assemblies manually. We can download [latest version package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net/) as the one in that guide is out of date.

After downloading the package, create a `bin` folder under `~\GetInvite`. Copy `Ical.Net.dll` and `NodaTime.dll`(dependency of `Ical.Net`) to this folder.

And some changes in `run.csx`.

```
// add assembly
#r "Ical.Net.dll"

// remove some unnecessary namespaces
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Ical.Net;
using Ical.Net.DataTypes;
using Ical.Net.CalendarComponents;
using Ical.Net.Serialization;

// remove async as the method has no await method
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    ... // remain the same
    // Event is deprecated in new version, use CalendarEvent
    var icalevent = new CalendarEvent{...}
    ... // remain the same
}
```

One more point, in `function.json` change `authLevel` from `function` to `anonymous`. Or you will get 401 error.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jerry! I will give it a try and let you know the results.